# .htaccess redirecting non SSL Domain to another SSL Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, https, ssl-certificate, redirect

I have the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old_domain.de$
RewriteRule (.*) https://new_domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The Problem is, the rule seem to only redirect www.old_domain.de or http://www.old_domain.de correctly, but does not redirect https://old_domain.de or old_domain.de (Which jumps to https:// automaticaly). I the second case I get the following error:

SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT

I already tried to rewrite https:// and non-www domains into http://www. but wasn't able to achieve the wanted results somehow. Probably I miss something Important here.

Is it possible there's something wrong with the https:// forcing at the .htaccess of my new domain?

Comment: Hi QCube. I have provided the working solution along with a tester for your question. In case of any issue, do comment or if that solves your problem upvote and accept the answer so that other SO users can benefit from the same.

Comment: Sure, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For redirecting http://www.old_domain.de or www.old_domain.de or http://old_domain.de or old_domain.de use the below code

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old_domain\.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://new_domain.de/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Your code is missing the `(www\.)?` in RewriteCond which will make the rewrite works irrespective of whether it contains a www or not.

You can test the same using htaccess tester at [link](https://htaccess.madewithlove.be?share=a38e65f3-fb92-52bb-8c91-dff31cf8df9d)

Similarly you should have a separate virtual host configured for **SSL (HTTPS)**. In that virtual host you also needs to copy the above code.

SSL is configured on port 443 to listen, so search for something similar to below code in your htaccess

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName www.old_domain.de
    ServerAlias old_domain.de

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/example/apache.key 

 </VirtualHost>
```

If you are still unable to find the file where virtual host listening on 443 is configured you can run the apache with the **-S flag** like below command

```
httpd -S or apachectl -S
```

This will give you the name of the file where virtual host listening on 443 is configured as in the below output

```
*:80     default server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (/etc/httpd/conf.d/eco.conf:1)
         port 80 namevhost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (/etc/httpd/conf.d/eco.conf:1)

*:443    default server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:1)
         port 443 namevhost xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:1)
```

For example `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf` is the file in which virtual host listening on 443 is configured.

Comment: Thank you for your Answer. It fixed one of the isues I had with the code up until now. I don't know if I undestood you right about the SSL virtual host. My old_domain doesn't have an SSL certificate and as my webspace is geting hosted I don't have access to the server or the command line or something like that (sadly). But the new domain does have SSL, but my Hoster is configuring the part that you describe I guess.

Comment: I think first part of your problem is solved. So now you are able to redirect all urls that doesn't contain https. For the second part of the problem, are you able to access your old_domain.de through https like https:// old_domain.de or https:// www.old_domain.de. If no than you can't redirect https:// old_domain.de to https:// new_domain.de. If yes than we need to find the virtual host configured for 443. Do let me know.